# zpool autoexpand doesn't change size of pool

Tags: solaris, zfs, storage-area-network

We have some old Solaris 10 servers (SunOS name 5.10 Generic_142909-17 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V490) now connected to our new IBM SAN. These Solaris servers still have mostly UFS file systems. A while back, we added a new 2 TB LUN from the SAN to one of the servers and started using it as a zpool with one ZFS file system defined on it - really simple. It worked great!

Recently we found that 2 TB wasn't enough, so we extended the LUN from 2 TB to 3 TB. `zpool list` showed

```
NAME         SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
solarisSYS  1.98T  1.84T   146G    92%  ONLINE  -
```

...both before and after the LUN was extended, as one would expect. `luxadm display` now shows

```
# luxadm display /dev/rdsk/c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0s2
DEVICE PROPERTIES for disk: /dev/rdsk/c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0s2
Vendor:               IBM     
Product ID:           2145            
Revision:             0000
Serial Num:           010020405e82XX00
Unformatted capacity: 3145728.000 MBytes
Read Cache:           Enabled
  Minimum prefetch:   0x0
  Maximum prefetch:   0x0
Device Type:          Disk device
Path(s):
/dev/rdsk/c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0s2
/devices/scsi_vhci/ssd@g600507640081017a080000000000004d:c,raw
```

Various sources said to do these, which I did:

```
# zpool set autoexpand=on solarisSYS
# zpool online -e solarisSYS c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0
# zpool export solarisSYS
# zpool import solarisSYS
# zpool list solarisSYS
NAME         SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
solarisSYS  1.98T  1.84T   146G    92%  ONLINE  -
```

Does autoexpand not work for our old version of Solaris? Or is there something else I can try?

Comment: I suspect that your version of ZFS does support `autoexpand`, else you wouldn't have been able to set the property.  What does `format` display for the LUN?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, It shows up as:  `16. c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0 <IBM-2145-0000-3.00TB>`

Comment: What is "zpool status solarisSYS" showing? Was the zpool created on c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0 or c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0s2?

Comment: <code>  pool: solarisSYS state: ONLINE scrub: none requestedconfig:        NAME                                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM        solarisSYS                               ONLINE       0     0     0          c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0  ONLINE       0     0     0`

Comment: [Interesting point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/githb/index.html):  "Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 Release: In this Solaris release, a system event or sysevent is provided when an a **disk is replaced** with larger disk or the disks in the pool are **replaced** with larger disks. ZFS has been enhanced to recognize these events..."  You're not **replacing** the disk, so I suspect ZFS isn't recognizing it as an "event".  I wonder what happens if you "replace" the disk with itself?  I'd recommend actually testing that on a non-production zpool first...

Comment: @AndrewHenle `# zpool replace solarisSYS c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0 c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/dsk/c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0s0 is part of active ZFS pool solarisSYS. Please see zpool(1M).
# zpool replace -f solarisSYS c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0 c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/dsk/c4t600507640081017A080000000000004Dd0s0 is part of active ZFS pool solarisSYS...`

Answer (score 1):

You may have export and reimport the pool or reboot and try the `zpool online -e` again.

This is definitely the case on Linux. But with your situation, it is worth a shot.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a reboot, though. I did export and import the pool and re-ran `zpool online -e` @ewwhite

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can't increase an actual disk's size, so zfs, or your version of zfs, may not have been designed/tested with that. Maybe you need to add a new LUN, use `zpool replace pool olddisk newdisk` instead, and then remove the old after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good solution, but there are some workarounds as described in "Expand LUN from HDS-VSP on existing ZPOOL (Community Discussion ID 2921641)".

It looks like the easiest for me would be to present a new LUN of the correct size, then use "zpool replace" to replace the old LUN with the new one. At least this can be done with no downtime. I haven't tried it yet, though.